# SQLite regex to find rows with strings not in a predefined set

Tags: regex, sqlite

I have a SQLite 3 column which can contain some different strings concatenated by `+`. Only some strings are valid, and I want to find rows where this column contains anything that is not part of the valid set of strings.

For example, these are valid strings

`1`  `2.4` `5X` `0A`

So if the column contains `1+2.4+0A` it is valid, but if it contains `1+2.4+6X` it is invalid (because `6X` is not part of the valid set). Likewise, `1 2.4` would be invalid since `1` and `2.4` must be separated by a `+`.

I tried experimenting with regex's but I can't seem to construct one that only allows the strings in the valid-list. Any help would be appreciated, and as previously stated I need this to work with SQLite 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(?:1|2\.4|5X|0A)` to have a group of all valid strings. Then you can check if a string begins with a valid string followed by any amount of valid strings preceded by a `+` till the end with `^(?:1|2\.4|5X|0A)(?:\+(?:1|2\.4|5X|0A))*$`.

That'll lead to something like

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat
       WHERE nmuloc REGEXP '^(?:1|2\.4|5X|0A)(?:\+(?:1|2\.4|5X|0A))*$';
```

to get the records with valid strings. (Negate to get the invalid ones.)

If you also want to allow empty strings to be valid, not sure from your description if these are OK, extend it to `^(?:1|2\.4|5X|0A)(?:\+(?:1|2\.4|5X|0A))*$|^$`.